# Multiple Filters in DAX COUNT (AND OR)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX and still trying to get the hang of the basics!

I'm stuck on a Power BI measure which needs to count the rows with the first filter, but only return a figure based on either the second or third filter. The below is not a valid syntax but demonstrates what I'm trying and failing to achieve with a AND OR statement.

In other words, count VIN in responses if Handover via app is 1 and either OPT In or OPT Out is 1.

Any thoughts how this can be done correctly?

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Responses'[VIN]),
    'Responses'[Handover Via App] IN { 1 } AND 'Responses'[OPT IN] IN { 1 } OR 'Responses'[OPT OUT] IN { 1 }
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAX you can use && = AND, || = OR. So your measure would work as:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(
            COUNTA(Responses[VIN]),
                FILTER(Responses, Responses[Handover via App] = 1 &&
                (Responses[OPT IN] = 1 || Responses[OPT OUT] = 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much - wasn't too far off!

Answer (score 0):

DAX now allows for the OR operator `||` to be used in a boolean filter argument, so you can write

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( Responses[VIN] ),
    Responses[Handover via App] = 1,
    Responses[OPT IN] = 1 || Responses[OPT OUT] = 1
)
```

Multiple arguments are combined using AND logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a solution to the problem using more than one filter on different tables.
Very simple just adding two filters.

```
CALCULATE(
    SUMX (
        FACT_VENDA,
        FACT_VENDA[Item_venda_qtde] * ([item_venda_vlr_sdesconto] + FACT_VENDA[item_venda_vlr_desconto]) + FACT_VENDA[item_venda_vlr_imposto]
    ),FILTER(
        FACT_VENDA,
        FACT_VENDA[nm_tipo_operacao] = {"VE"}
    ),FILTER(
        DIM_PRODUTO,
        DIM_PRODUTO[cod_cad_produto] = 1   
    )
)
```